# Cannot install Certificate on android

Tags: android, certificate

I have a certificate used for wifi 802.1x auth that I am unable to install on android phones. Most Android devices are able to use the built-in root CA certs to sign on, but not Samsung devices without manually installing the cert. However whenever I try to install the cert (on any android device) I receive an error that the certificate requires a private key. I've tried re-exporting the key, changing the key to cer, crt, and pem, both with base 64 and der. Nothing seems to allow me to install the certificate and always results in the private key required toast. Any guidance on what android is expecting or how to get my certificate installed?